# Azure Service Fabric - unable to delete any default NAT rules

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I need to block access to RDP, and there seems to be no way of doing that,  I'm either getting a false "success" message and the rule remains, or the error below

```
Failed to delete inbound NAT rule 'LoadBalancerBEAddressNatPool.0'. Error: Adding or updating NAT Rules when NAT pool is present on loadbalancer /subscriptions/... is not supported. To modify the load balancer, pass in all NAT rules unchanged or remove the LoadBalancerInboundNatRules property from your PUT request.
```

Comment: Are you running in Azure? Are you using the portal, or ARM?

Comment: @LoekD Azure Portal

Comment: Can you give it a try using an ARM template?

Comment: I have my SF cluster and the LB defined in an ARM template. Even removing the InboundNatRules from the template and redeploying did not delete the NAT rules.  I guess I need to recreate the cluster and the LB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ARM template based approach I had to remove `inboundNatPools` in `loadBalancingRules`

```
    // "inboundNatPools": [
    //   {
    //     "name": "LoadBalancerBEAddressNatPool",
    //     "properties": {
    //       "backendPort": "3389",
    //       "frontendIPConfiguration": {
    //         "id": "[variables('lbIPConfig0')]"
    //       },
    //       "frontendPortRangeEnd": "4500",
    //       "frontendPortRangeStart": "3389",
    //       "protocol": "tcp"
    //     }
    //   }
    // ]
```

and `loadBalancerInboundNatPools` in `networkProfile` of the *VMSS*

```
      "networkProfile": {
        "networkInterfaceConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('nicName'), '-0')]",
            "properties": {
              "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                  "name": "[concat(parameters('nicName'),'-',0)]",
                  "properties": {
                    "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
                      {
                        "id": "[variables('lbPoolID0')]"
                      }
                    ],
                    // "loadBalancerInboundNatPools": [
                    //   {
                    //     "id": "[variables('lbNatPoolID0')]"
                    //   }
                    // ],
                    "subnet": {
                      "id": "[variables('subnet0Ref')]"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "primary": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

and then deploy again.

For you that would mean to extract the ARM template with the *Automation* feature in the Resource Group, remove the entries as stated above and then deploy again.